# Input mask Jquery plugin should not move the characters before

Tags: jquery, input, mask

I have a text box with a mask

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".input").inputmask({

        "mask": "***/****/*****", 

    });
});
```

**Html**

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Tpr6N/116/

When i delete the character in between it should not move the next characters to the deleted position and append an empty space in the end.It should only empty the deleted position and rest of the characters should stay as such.

Any idea how to implement this?